# Issues with djecjni.dll

Tags: java, pervasive

While registering `djecjni.dll` from command prompt, am getting the following error: 
`LoadLibrary("C:\Software\Pervasive\Cosmos9\Common\djecjni.dll") failed`.

I used following command to register dll from command prompt: 
`regsvr32 "C:\Software\Pervasive\Cosmos9\Common\djecjni.dll"`

Am trying to run djecjni.dll file from Java but am getting this error :

```
 The operating system cannot run C:\Software\Pervasive\Cosmos9\Common\djecjni.dll


 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: djecjni.dll (The operating system cannot run
 C:\Software\Pervasive\Cosmos9\Common\djecjni.dll. )
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:993)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:962)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:465)
 at DataJunction.ec.NEngine.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
 at DataJunction.ec.Engine.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I've added the dll in the path but still the dll cannot be run. Could anyone suggest some tips to resolve the above 2 issue?

Answer (score 0):

What OS?  Based on the error, I would guess that the DLL is 32 bit and you only have 64 bit Java installed.  Could also be that Java isn't installed.

Comment: OS is Windows XP version 2002 SP3. I tried several options but am still unsuccessful in resolving it. Can you please suggest some resolution?

Comment: Is there any thing more to the regsvr32 error? Also, what is your end goal?  Can you run maps from the map designer?

Comment: My objective is to run the dj from a java program and so it needs to call the djecjni.dll. But, while trying to call the dll it throws a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: djecjni.dll (The operating system cannot run C:\Software\Pervasive\Cosmos9\Common\djecjni.dll

Comment: Well, i tried several different ways to register the dll but the end result was same. Am assuming that in order to run the call the dll from java app, it first needs to be registered successfully, once it is successfull, i can run the dj from java - i hope:-)